# I can not use OpenCV with Eclipse (plugin CDT) on windows 10

Tags: opencv, mingw, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-neon

**Hello all,,**
    My objective is to use **OpenCV** **with Eclipse (plugin CDT)**. Firstly, I **downloaded the CDT plugin from help » install new software.** After that, I added the correct cdt 9.2 url and after downloading the whole 34 files, eclipse had to restart.
    After applying all the steps in this link
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html
 **I got these errors in the screenshot** 
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnq5G.jpg)

Best Regards

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a C/C++ compiler installed. Install the `g++` package from your package manager and try again.

Comment: I moved from Eclipse to visual studio platform, because OpenCv was successfully configured with visual studio community 2017